# An error in proot happening while running NetHunter

Tags: linux, kali-linux, termux

When I tried to install Kali NetHunter in termux using:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
pkg install wget
wget -O install-nethunter-termux https://offs.ec/2MceZWr
chmod +x install-nethunter-termux
./install-nethunter-termux
```

All was successful. But when I tried to run it, an error was occured:

```
proot error: execve("/usr/bin/env"): Function not implemented
proot info: possible causes:
  * the program is a script but its interpreter (eg. /bin/sh) was not found;
  * the program is an ELF but its interpreter (eg. ld-linux.so) was not found;
  * the program is a foreign binary but qemu was not specified;
  * qemu does not work correctly (if specified);
  * the loader was not found or doesn't work.
fatal error: see `proot --help`.
proot error: can't chmod '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/proot-6214-XYtP8t': No such file or directory
```

What's wrong and how to fix it?